# Java. Вывести объект, если переменная совпала с элементом массива

Tags: java, массивы, for

Есть массив с объектами.

```
Person[] stud;
stud = new Person[] {
 new Person("Фамилия А.Б",1,new int[]{4,4,4,4,5}),
new Person("Фамилия Ш.Д",1,new int[]{3,4,4,3,5})
};
```

Считываю данные ввода пользователя

```
Scanner mark = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Как мне вывести все данные Person, если переменная mark совпала с элементов массива оценок?
Вот сам конструктор

```
Person(String n, int g, int[]b){
this.name = n;
this.group = g;
this.balls = Arrays.copyOf(b,b.length);
}
```

Comment: 1. Идти по массиву студентов.
2. На каждом студенте заходит в массив оценок и делать проверку.

Comment: Как зайти в массив оценок?

Comment: Обратиться к Person.balls, не?

Comment: Все спасибо решил